# WP8 WebBrowser Control showing error with security certificate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using the webbrowser control within my windows phone 8 app. Now I want to navigate to a https:// page, which have problems with the security certificate. So I see this picture:

[image: webbrowser]

If I click on the link 'Continue to website (not recommended)', nothing would happen. I see exact the same page? If I try this in IE on Windows Phone then it is no problem. So how can I activate the second link? Is there an opurtinity to hide this screen and navigate directly to the page?

Comment: Is it a Self signed cert?

Comment: Currently I'm testing with a website which haven't any type of certificate. But later it will be a self signed certificate.

Comment: I don't believe self-signed are allowed in apps. You must be using https in the example above?